# Sitecore 9 Hardware Capacity Calculator

Tags: scaling, infrastructure

We are planning to move application on Sitecore XP 9.1 on premises and looking references to calculate the hardware requirement. The load on the application is 5M users per month.I have checked the Sitecore Installation guidelines however it doesn't specify hardware requirement for XP instances like processing,reporting,collection etc. Please share any details if you have.

Thanks.

Comment: There are so many unknowns that could affect performance on this, which is why there are very few guides. A lot will depend on how performant the application is written. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/043375 - that might give you a starting point if you are going to Azure PaaS. But even then, those sizes are underestimated in my experience.

Comment: The only correct answer to this question is "pay a good Sitecore consultant to review your requirements and architect the solution".